# Convex partitioning of polygons in boost geometry or polygon

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry, boost-polygon

Is it possible to compute a **partitioning in convex sub-polygons** using boost::geometry or boost::polygon?

I have a concave (non-convex) polygon and I would like to transform it into convex sub-polygons. Can boost do that?

I am not after an optimal solution... e.g. the Hertel-Mehlhorn algorithm would be great for instance.

I have checked docs for both libs [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html) and [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/polygon/doc/index.htm) (and in many blogs or websites) and the answer is not obvious to me...

Comment: If you had some sample code here showing what you tried to solve the problem that would make it a lot better than what is pretty vague right now. What data structures do you have? How does Boost come into play?

Comment: This might not cover your use case, but you can have a look at Boost Polygon's `polygon_set_data`, which supports triangulation through `get_triangles`.

Comment: This is interesting!